# Test Class for Controller with many if conditions:

Tags: unit-test

How to write test class for following controller. I am able to write it for only one if conditions.

```
public with sharing class ControllerExtension {

Id Param1= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param1');
Id Param2= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param2');
Id Param3= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param3');
Id Param4= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param4');
Id Param5= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param5');

public string returnSomeValue(){
    return someValue;
}

ApexPages.StandardController stdCtrl;

public ControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.oddObj = (Order)controller.getRecord();
     }   
}     

public pageReference eventpage(){
    string parameter = returnSomeValue();
     if(Param1 != null){
         Order navigation=(Order)stdCtrl.getRecord();
         if(navigation.Id != null){
              if(parameter != null){
             pageReference navigatePage= new pageReference ('/apex/Page2?Id='+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param1')+'&Param3='+navigation.Id+'&'+parameter+'&ok=true');
             navigatePage.setRedirect(true);
             return navigatePage;
             }else{
                 pageReference navigatePage= new pageReference ('/apex/Page2?Id='+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param1')+'&Param3='+navigation.Id+'&ok=true');
             navigatePage.setRedirect(true);
             return navigatePage;
             }
         }else{
              if(parameter != null){
             pageReference navigatePage= new pageReference ('/apex/Page2?Id='+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param1')+'&'+parameter+'&ok=true');
             navigatePage.setRedirect(true);
             return navigatePage;
             }else{
                 pageReference navigatePage= new pageReference ('/apex/Page2?Id='+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Param1')+'&ok=true');
             navigatePage.setRedirect(true);
             return navigatePage;
             }
         }
     }else{
         Order navigation=(Order)stdCtrl.getRecord();
         if(navigation.Id != null){
             if(parameter != null){
             pageReference navigatePage= new pageReference ('/apex/Page2?&Param3='+navigation.Id+'&'+parameter);
             navigatePage.setRedirect(true);
             return navigatePage;
             }else{
                 pageReference navigatePage= new pageReference ('/apex/Page2?&Param3='+navigation.Id);
             navigatePage.setRedirect(true);
             return navigatePage;
             }
         }else{
             if(parameter != null){
             pageReference navigatePage= new pageReference ('/apex/Page2?'+parameter);
             navigatePage.setRedirect(true);
             return navigatePage;
             }else{
                 pageReference navigatePage= new pageReference ('/apex/Page2');
             navigatePage.setRedirect(true);
             return navigatePage;
             }
         }
     }
     return null;
    }
```

Comment: You can write multiple test methods in your test class, each covering one if condition. When you test class is run, each of the test methods will contribute to the code coverage. Is there anything specific you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code requires satisfying 9 branches in order to get 100% coverage. Even worse, you can't cover the final condition (return null) because the other logic will never allow you to reach this line of code. The best you can get to is 98% coverage, and requiring up to 9 unit tests. Instead, you can get 100% coverage using just one unit test by optimizing your program flow.

Here's my basic optimization of your code:

```
public PageReference eventPage() {
    Order navigation=(Order)stdCtrl.getRecord();
    String parameter = returnSomeValue();
    PageReference ref = Page.Page2;
    if(navigation.Id != null) {
        ref.getParameters().put('Param3',navigation.Id);
    }
    if(Param1 != null) {
        ref.getParameters().put('Id',Param1);
        ref.getParameters().put('ok','true');
    }
    if(parameter!=null) {
        ref.getParameters().put(parameter.split('=')[0], parameter.split('=',2)[1]);
    }
    ref.setRedirect(true);
    return ref;
}
```

This change removes over 50% of the original code. Even better, I only need to provide an existing record (navigation.Id != null), a Param1 value, and get returnSomeValue() to return a value. A total of 3 branches to cover, and I can do it all in a single test method by providing all three values at once.

You'll want to spend time studying how optimization can make your code easier to read, easier to test, and easier to maintain.